# Can mock or other stubs be used in integration tests?

Tags: c#, .net-core, integration-testing, xunit

There is a controller:

```
[HttpGet("list")]
public Task<MyModel> GetListAsync([FromQuery] MyType form, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    => _rService.GetFilterAsync(form, cancellationToken);
```

Which calls the method:

```
public async Task<MyModel> GetFilterAsync(MyType form,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    _validator.ValidateAndThrow(form);
    var myModel = await _rRepository.RelsAsync(form, cancellationToken);
    var infoModel =
        await _abcService.GetReleaseInfoAsync(myModel.Items.Select(r => r.Id), cancellationToken);
}
```

can I mock `_abcService.GetReleaseInfoAsync`?

In Unit tests, I can do this.
I put `var mock = new Mock<T>();` in the constructor of the test class, create an instance of the class under test there, to which I pass `mock.Object`. And then, through this instance of the tested class, I call the method I need. Everything works here. However, in integration tests, I do not create an instance of the tested class, as in Unit tests. I am generating a POST / GET request that is sent to the controller. And the controller calls the required method in which you need to install the mock.
I don't understand how exactly to screw the mock to this method. And is it even possible to do this.
It is clear that then you can perform `Setup` or `Verify`.

Comment: Have a look at `Mock<T>.Setup`

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay
Answered in main description